# RabbitMQ - Greater than 255 max priority

Tags: rabbitmq

I need to enqueue messages based on time. Every message has a "start date" and the message with the earliest start date needs to be at the front of the queue. Is there a way to do this with RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is clear that priority must be between 0 and 255 (https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html). You could use multiple queues but keep in mind that priority queues have a performance cost.